# How to view json objects in opera in WebDriver Automation Tests(java)

Tags: java, json, webdriver, opera

I executed selenium webdriver tests for nodejs projects am unable to view the json objects in opera(11.64).I get a modal box(download file) asking  to save the file but even after downloaling it shows "No registered application for this extension."
    Any idea on this. Manually I can view it when I added json viewer extension or JsonHero extention.But I face this issue only when I execute the tests(webdriver-version 2.21.0).

Answer (score 0):

With Opera 12, I had no issue opening a local JSON file with a drag and drop on the browser window.

If it's a link to a JSON file on a Web page, what is the mime-type of the file? It is defined by [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627). So the server should send.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

or something else? If Opera doesn't understand the application/json, you can teach him in the Preferences by associating this mime type with the browser itself.